# How to pass Array in controller to JS in cshtml - MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I am a beginner to develop .Net MVC 5 application. But I have some problems with passing an array from the controller to JS in cshtml but I don't know how do I do, anyone to inform me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttbKa.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03lLL.png)

JS:

```js
var areaChartData = {
  labels: ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık'],
  datasets: [{
          label: 'Çıkan Ürün',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointRadius: false,
          pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
          pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          data: [10,10,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,20,10,111]
      }]
}
```

Controller:

```js
public ActionResult Index() {

    double[] giren = new double[11];
    return View();
}
```

How can I post the array sent to "data" in the JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

controller:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public ActionResult Index()
    {
       double[] value= new double[13];
       ViewBag.DataPoints1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
       return view();
    }
```

JS

```
 datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Name',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                pointRadius: false,
                pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                data: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints1)
            },
```

"data" can call values as ViewBag from controller

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly pass the value from Controller to `JS` in `cshtml` part. First bind the `cshtml` then get the element in `DOM`, so that `DOM` will load with the value in `cshtml` element which is coming from controller.

Then you can access the value from `cshtml` element to `JS`. This is the cycle.

You Can refer below article.
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-using-javascript-with-ajax-and-razor-partial-views